# Ember.js: Iterating through multiple models set on controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to declare two models to be loaded by my controller.

I am not using the `model`,`beforeModel`, or `afterModel` hooks because:

1. I don't have to implement `loading` routes/templates
2. I can load each model independently in the page (like lazy loading)

I am using the setupController hook in my route as so:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var that = this;

        controller.set('model', {
            stations: that.store.find('station'),
            packages: that.store.find('package'),
        });
}
```

My controller is an `Ember.Controller`.

In order to iterate through these models in Handlebars I have to use `model.stations.content.content` which makes me think I am doing something wrong:

```
{{#each station in model.stations.content.content}}
//  .....
{{/each}}
```

Is there a better way to set these models on the controller or use a different controller type or something?

Answer (score 2):

@MilkyWayJoe's method is definitely the right way to do it if you realize that if you have a large model or your AJAX requests take a long time, your UI will go blank and [Ember will try to find a `loading` process](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) while the model is loading.

@Chaosekie suggested the answer to my question which was to wait for the promise to load the model from the store to fulfill *then* set the property on the controller.

I.e. in the `route`:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.store.find('station').then(function(stations) {
            controller.set('stations',stations);
        });
        this.store.find('package').then(function(packages) {
            controller.set('packages', packages);
        });
}
```

This allows one to iterate through both models using the 'normal' way in Handlebars:

```
{{#each package in packages}}
// ....
{{/each}}

{{#each station in stations}}
// ....
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your model to return `Ember.RSVP.hash` which will act like a *promise bag*, and within the scope of the hash you fill up the attributes `stations` and `packages` with your data, so when the model gets resolved it will set that hash schema as the model in your controller:

```
[...]
model: function() {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
        stations: this.store.find('station'),
        packages: this.store.find('package')
    });
} 
[...]
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each item in model.stations}}
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each item in model.packages}}
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

(See [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dotogozosa/1/edit?html,js,output))

Comment: I did this before but my models are huge which was making the page load really slow, and is why I gave an explanation as to why I wasn't using the `model` hooks in the question

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a new object for your model.

You could do the following in your controller:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
  controller.set('model', model);
  this.stations().then(function(value){
    controller.set('stations', value);  
  });
}
```

Where stations is:

```
stations: function() {
  return this.store.find('station');
}
```

Then you can use `stations` in your template in the same way as you would use model. Check out [this example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/foganu/12/edit?html,js,output)

But a controller should really only decorate one model, you might consider creating nested routes ( which will give you nested controllers ).

Comment: wow thanks for the example and everything!  I still run into the same problem using the model hook where if it takes a while to load I will get a blank screen or have to implement a loading template.    HOWEVER, your method of loading the model into the store BEFORE setting it on the controller did the trick!